# Карусель как на apple или instagram и т д

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Привет всем.
Я очень хочу сделать такой слайдер как у [apple.com](http://www.apple.com/) на главной странице,или как у instram, vk stories там такие же. Нашел я вот такой код в просторах интернета код, но она не идеальная) но это лучшее что нашел) 
Проблема в коде то что, неравномерно заполняется да и вид ужасная. Вот собственно и сам: codepen.io/loic_album/pen/ALkrwO

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри что такое Slick. Тебе должно понравиться. Через него можно сделать почти любую карусель, но с анимацией блоков внутри придется играться самому

Comment: Желательно привести пример кода, чтобы ответ был максимально полезен для тех, кто в дальнейшем наткнется на эту тему.

Comment: Есть хороший сервис по очистке css? желательно онлайн